# How to display student names along with ID with above average GPA in a structure array

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, struct

I have a task to display the names, ID, GPA of students who got above average GPA.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct student{

    string name;
    char stdid[20];
    int age;
    char gender;
    float gpa;

};


int main() {

    int amount;
    float sum=0.0, average;

    struct student std[40];

    struct student *ptr = NULL;

    ptr = std;

    cout<<"enter the amount of students you want to input"<<endl;
    cin>>amount;


    for (int i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        cout<<"please enter details such as name, ID, age, gender and GPA for student "<< (i+1)<<endl;
        cout<<"Student ID : "<<endl;
        cin>>ptr->stdid;
        cout<<"Name : "<<endl;
        cin>>ptr->name;
        cout<<"Age : "<<endl;
        cin>>ptr->age;
        cout<<"Gender : "<<endl;
        cin>>ptr->gender;
        cout<<"GPA : "<<endl;
        cin>>ptr->gpa;
        sum += ptr->gpa;
    }

    average = sum/amount;
    cout << "Average GPA = " << average;


return 0;
}
```

For Example if a user input 3 students in the program such as;

student 1: John, 3.5 GPA

student 2: Bob, 4.0 GPA

student 3: Mike, 2.3 GPA

Average GPA : 3.23

then the output will show name, ID and GPA of all students that has above average GPA of 3.23

Comment: You never increment `ptr` to point to the following student in `std`. Also a bad idea to use `std` as a variable name: may conflict with `namespace std`

Comment: [I was surprised to find gcc doesn't complain about a namespace `std` mixed with a variable `std`](https://ideone.com/vW1d25). I'll look up why later. But even if the compiler doesn't get confused with an identifier named `std`, the human might.

Comment: ok! i have now changed std variable to stdnt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You must learn to iterate over an array, before you go any further with this project.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you consider the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container for storing the `student` objects and the algorithm [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) for calculating the average:

```
std::vector<student> students;

// ...
// fill the vector of students
// ...

// calculate the sum of all GPAs
float sum = std::accumulate(students.begin(), students.end(), 0.0f,
                            [](float acc, const student& elem) {
                               return acc + elem.gpa;       
                            }
);

// calculate the average GPA
auto avg = sum / students.size();
```

For displaying a `student` object you can define the following *output stream operator*:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, student const& s) {
   os << s.stdid << " " << s.gpa << '\n';
}
```

Then, you can iterate over the whole collection of `student` objects and display only those whose GPA is above the average:

```
for (auto const& student: students)
   if (student.gpa > avg)
      std::cout << student; // call the output stream operator defined above
```